# MenuItem Icons in WPF Menu disappear

Tags: wpf

I have this XAML to render a menu from my view model:

```
<DockPanel>
    <Menu DockPanel.Dock="Top" ItemsSource="{Binding MenuItems}">
        <Menu.Resources>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ImageBrush" Color="Blue"/>

            <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:MenuItemViewModel}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ChildMenuItems}">
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="MenuItem">
                        <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding Command}" />
                        <Setter Property="Icon">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <Image Source="{Binding Path=Icon, Converter={fa:ImageSourceConverter}, ConverterParameter={StaticResource ImageBrush}}" />
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Style>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemContainerStyle>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Label Content="{Binding Header}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </Menu.Resources>
    </Menu>
</DockPanel>
```

All works fine except that icons disappear after first menu  opening.  Lets say I have two menus with one child item each, I open menu 'A' and child menu shows icon.  Then I open menu 'B' and child menu shows icon.  ThenIopen menu 'A' again and child menu does not show icon.  Only child menu in menu 'B' is showing it's icon.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Image` is a `Control` which can only have one parent, so you will see this behavior. Create an `Image` Control in **resource** and set to non-shared with the `x:Shared` XAML attribute:

```
<Menu DockPanel.Dock="Top" ItemsSource="{Binding MenuItems}">
            <Menu.Resources>
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ImageBrush" Color="Blue"/>
                <Image x:Key="menuIcon" x:Shared="false" Source="{Binding Path=Icon, Converter={fa:ImageSourceConverter}, ConverterParameter={StaticResource ImageBrush}}" />
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:MenuItemViewModel}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ChildMenuItems}">
                    <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemContainerStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="MenuItem">
                            <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding Command}" />
                            <Setter Property="Icon" Value="{StaticResource menuIcon}" />
                        </Style>
                    </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Label Content="{Binding Header}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            </Menu.Resources>
        </Menu>
```

Check my sample [here](https://github.com/Myfreedom614/WPF-Samples/tree/master/WpfMenuApplication1)